# terminal's git not working

Tags: git, terminal

```
AppledeMacBook-Pro:a apple$ git
2015-06-01 22:03:36.309 xcodebuild[1136:25124] CPCodePilotPlugin.m:23 +    [CPCodePilotPlugin load]; CODE PILOT: CURRENT_XCODE_VERSION: 0     CURRENT_XCODE_REVISION: 0
Jun  1 22:03:36 AppledeMacBook-Pro.local xcodebuild[1136] <Warning>:     CGSConnectionByID: 0 is not a valid connection ID.
Jun  1 22:03:36 AppledeMacBook-Pro.local xcodebuild[1136] <Warning>: Invalid Connection ID 0
** INTERNAL ERROR: Uncaught exception **
Exception: Error (1000) creating CGSWindow
Stack:
  0  0x00007fff85a78024 __exceptionPreprocess (in CoreFoundation)
  1  0x00007fff87f9276e objc_exception_throw (in libobjc.A.dylib)
  2  0x00007fff85a77eed +[NSException raise:format:] (in CoreFoundation)
  3  0x00007fff8b208306 _NXCreateWindowWithStyleMask (in AppKit)
  4  0x00007fff8b2080a2 _NSCreateWindow (in AppKit)
...
...
 31  0x0000000109e99ee4 __46-[XCPluginManager loadPluginBundle:forDomain:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
 32  0x00000001082698f2 DVTInvokeWithFailureHint (in DVTFoundation)
 33  0x0000000109e99c6c -[XCPluginManager loadPluginBundle:forDomain:] (in DevToolsCore)
 34  0x0000000109e99704 __46-[XCPluginManager findAndLoadPluginsInDomain:]_block_invoke (in DevToolsCore)
 35  0x000000010825081d -[DVTPlugInManager _allowNonApplePlugInsFromDescriptors:error:] (in DVTFoundation)
 36  0x0000000108250a9e -[DVTPlugInManager _checkNonApplePlugIns] (in DVTFoundation)
 37  0x0000000108250b14 -[DVTPlugInManager initializePlugIns:] (in DVTFoundation)
 38  0x00000001087d77e4 _IDEInitializeOtherPlugInStuff (in IDEFoundation)
 39  0x00000001087d8bbc IDEInitialize (in IDEFoundation)
 40  0x0000000108ddd02f -[Xcode3CommandLineBuildTool run] (in Xcode3Core)
 41  0x00000001080949be (in xcodebuild)
 42  0x00007fff89c1d5c9 start (in libdyld.dylib)

sh: line 1:  1139 Abort trap: 6 /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk macosx -find     git 2> /dev/null
git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH
```

I don't know where the problem is.I hope to see the people can help me, thank you very much

my macbook pro -> OS X Yosemite version:10.10.3

Comment: either git's not installed, or it's not in your path...

Comment: Looks like the key error message is git: error: unable to find utility "git", not a developer tool or in PATH' - try http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/18470

Answer (score 2):

I am also using Mac and I remember I did `Xcode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Install Command Line Tools`. This action provide me the correct git tool, you can have a try.